# Listener in Testng

Tags: selenium, testng

I have created a listener class in my project. Now what I have read in web there are two methods to add a listener either to your class or to testng file.

[image: MyProjectFolderStructue]

Please check in the folder structure. For now, I m using it like this in my java class but it is giving me error as in image attached:

`@Listeners({Test.tes.Utils.ListenerUse.class})`

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Listeners({Test.tes.Utils.ListenerUse.class})  , I have used this and it is giving error on Test.tes with a red line.

Comment: Again, what is the error?

Comment: error is : Test.tes cannot be resolved to a type

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshots, I understand that your test class `HomeTestCases.java` resides in the package `Test.test.MyHomepageTestCases` in `src/test/java`

You are trying to refer to the listener `ListenerToUse.java` that resides in  the package `Test.tes.Utils`in `src/main/java`.

When you use `@Listeners(Test.tes.MyHomepageTestCases.MyHomepageTestCases.ListenerToUse.class)`
Here you are basically telling Java to look for the listener class `ListenerToUse` inside `Test.tes.MyHomepageTestCases.MyHomepageTestCases` (as a nested class), but that's not the case because `ListenerToUse` is NOT a embedded class inside `MyHomepageTestCases.java`.

To fix the problem please do the following:

- **Change:**  `@Listeners(Test.tes.MyHomepageTestCases.MyHomepageTestCases.ListenerToUse.class)`
- **To:** `@Listeners(Test.tes.Utils.ListenerToUse.class)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is you're mixing the package of your Listener, and the package of the class where you want to add it.

**Your code now:**

```
@Listeners(Test.tes.MyHomePageTestCases.MyHomePageTestCases.ListenerUse.class)
```

**Correct package:**

```
@Listeners(Test.tes.Utils.ListenerUse.class)
```

However, you've named your package "Test", which is (besides breaking Java naming conventions -> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) clashing with the TestNG Test class. On your screenshot, I can see that "Test" is grayed out. If you hover with your mouse over it, you'll probably see Eclipse has resolved it as "org.testng.annotations.Test". So you have two options:

1. Name your packages properly and try again
2. Expand the imports sections of your HomeTestCases class; manually add:

   import Test.tes.Utils.ListenerUse;

and delete the following:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
```

Comment: Hi, sorry yes in the screenshot i used the wrong package and then i corrected it like you mentioned , but whn i m using it like this @Listeners(Test.tes.Utils.ListenerUse.class), i m getting a red line (complie error) on Test.tes and on hovering over it , it says "Test.tes" cannot be resolved to a type".